# CollectionView With Endless Scrolling - Too laggy

Tags: android, .net, maui

I have a CollectionView that I will initially load with 25 items, as the user scrolls I want to load more items, add them to the item source for the CollectionView and have the items appear at the end of the CollectionView.

I can achieve this, but my app always stutters and lags while its adding the items to the CollectionView ItemSource (ObservableCollection).

Here is a really simple example

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace myapp;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> collection = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();

    public bool isLoading { get; set; } = false;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var items = FetchItems();

        foreach (var item in items)
            collection.Add(item);

        svItems.Scrolled += (object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var scrollView = sender as ScrollView;

            var curScroll = scrollView.ScrollY;
            var maxScroll = scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height;
            var percScroll = scrollView.ScrollY / maxScroll;

            if (percScroll > 0.75 && !isLoading)
            {
                isLoading = true;
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var items = FetchItems();

                    foreach(var item in items ) 
                        collection.Add(item);

                    isLoading = false;
                });
            }
        };

        lvItems.ItemsSource = collection;
    }

    private IEnumerable<DataModel> FetchItems()
    {
        //generate 25 items
        var items = Enumerable.Range(collection.Count, 25)
                              .Select(n => new DataModel { Title = $"Item {n}", FullName = n.ToString() })
                              .ToList();

        //Simulate some time passing 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        return items;
    }
}

public class DataModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

And the xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="reddapp.MainPage">

    <ScrollView x:Name="svItems">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="5,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">
            <CollectionView x:Name="lvItems" BackgroundColor="#25405E">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,15,0,15" ColumnDefinitions="5*, 1*" RowDefinitions="*">
                            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        Margin="25,1,25,0"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                        FontFamily="Font_11"
                                        TextColor="White" 
                                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                                       />
                                <Label Text="{Binding FullName}"
                                        FontSize="10"
                                        Margin="25,1,25,0"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                        FontFamily="Font_11"
                                        TextColor="White" 
                                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                                       />
                            </VerticalStackLayout>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

I have also tried creating my own inherited version of ObservableCollection which adds all the items to the underlying item collection, then does the update by firing

```
this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
```

But its just as laggy.

Is there any kind of EndlessListBox or EndlessCollectionView solutions out there that are commonly used?

Would this thing just be better off made in Java instead?

Comment: Get back on the mainthread before adding items. The problem with adding them on background thread is that each add triggers a UI update. If you add on mainthread, there should be only one ui update. Unclear whether your custom one did any better, since you don’t show code. As for whether it would be better in java, that is a matter of opinion, so out-of-scope for StackOverflow. But obviously, native solutions can reach superior performance compared to cross-platform solutions. Its not necessary to go to java for that: Xamarin.Android (.Net for Android) avoids all the problems of Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: [OPINION] I never encountered any performance issues when using Xamarin.Android and .iOS. Same as writing native. Had to write UI twice, but having both products in a single language was a huge win. I spent years trying to make Xamarin.Forms pay off. Never did, in my lengthy experience. Maui isn’t there yet either, but I am determined to help get it there. .Net cross-platform is great. But the UI piece isn’t. Mapping to native controls is fundamentally difficult. Too many bugs. I prefer rendering to a bitmap. Like Flutter, Unity 3d, AvaloniaUI, and Uno Platform allow. Maui needs that option.

Comment: Thanks, I will give Xamarin.Android a try.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be replicated on my side. To fix the issue, which means to make the `CollectionView` **smoother** and **less delay** when adding new items to it, you can try to remove the `VerticalStackLayout` as `VerticalStackLayout` has the height of its content, and ListView/CollectionView has no height except if you set one through `HeightRequest`.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="svItems">
       <CollectionView x:Name="lvItems">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <!--Omitted for brevity --->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>   
</ScrollView>
```